# Codeigniter3.0のForm Validationで複数のルールに同じcallbackを指定している場合

Tags: php, codeigniter

3カ所inputのあるフォームをPOSTした際、
その3つともに同じcallbackを指定しているのですが
そのcallback function内でどのPOSTかを見分ける方法ってありますか？

例えば、

```
public function hoge()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("hoge1", "ホゲ1", "callback__validate_hoge");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("hoge2", "ホゲ2", "callback__validate_hoge");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("hoge3", "ホゲ3", "callback__validate_hoge");

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        //処理    
    } else //処理
}

function _validate_hoge()
{
    echo "This is ".$whichhoge;
}
```

こうあるとき、$whichhogeにhoge1と入れたりする方法ってありませんか？
また、このようにruleに独自コールバックしかないような場合は$this->input->post();で取ってきて
中身をループさせて処理させたほうが良いと思いますか？
よろしくおねがいします。

追記：
自己解決しましたが、最後の質問は引き続きお聞きしたいです。
form_validationを使う利点として何かあるかな、と。
思いつくのはルールを増やしたいときくらいですが、既に用意されているルールも限りがありますし、どうなんでしょうか。

解決策は

```
public function hoge()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("hoge1", "ホゲ1", "callback__validate_hoge[hoge1]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("hoge2", "ホゲ2", "callback__validate_hoge[hoge2]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("hoge3", "ホゲ3", "callback__validate_hoge[hoge3]");

    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        //処理    
    } else //処理
}

function _validate_hoge($value, $whichhoge)
{
    return $value." is ".$whichhoge; //ex.) ホゲ1 is hoge1
}
```

echoはおかしかったですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

他のフレームワークでもよく見かける形ですが、CodeIgniter の form_validation は「汎用的な細かいルールを組み合わせて各入力値を検証・フィルタする」というものです。

- ルールが細分化されている
- ルールはどのフィールドで使われるかを気にせず、入力値の処理のみを行う
- ルールの組み合わせが簡単に行える

という特徴から、ルールの再利用性や、組み合わせた場合のわかりやすさが期待できます。

一方、「ruleに独自コールバックしかない」ということは、前述の思想とは逆に、フィールド・フォームごとにひとかたまりのロジックを設けて検証・フィルタする、という設計になっているのでしょう。

是非はともかく、その場合は無理に form_validation を使わなくてもいいかなと思います。

```
function _validate_hoge($value, $whichhoge)
{
    return $value." is ".$whichhoge; //ex.) ホゲ1 is hoge1
}
```

この処理がバリデーションやフィルタなのかは疑問ですが・・・。

Comment: ありがとうございます。form_validationのメリットが分かりやすいです。  
  
一応例はあれですが、実際はバリデーションの役割を書いています。  
追加でお聞きしたいのですが、もしフィールド・フォームごとに処理する関数に投げるなら$this->input->post()の中身を全部その関数に投げて、中でループさせて1つ1つ処理することとなるでしょうけど、Codeigniterのform_validationも内部的にはそういうループ→1つ1つ処理→全部パスしたらtrue、っていうような動作なのでしょうかね？  
system/librariesのForm_validation.php見てみましたけど複雑でよく分かりませんでした。

Comment: @John そのループに相当するのはこのあたりでしょうか。 https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.3/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L470-L494 `$this->_field_data` は `set_rules` で設定されるようです。 https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.3/system/libraries/Form_validation.php#L238-L247

Comment: わざわざ該当箇所まですみません。独自関数作ってform_validationを使うのは辞めようと思いましたが、思いの外めんどうなのと、form_validation使ってると$this->input->post()の中に計らってそれぞれ値を戻してくれたりしていて、やはり便利なのですが、callbackに入れられる$paramには制限があるのと、示してくれたコード中にあるようpreg_matchでとってきてるようでメタ文字をエスケープしなければいけないので結局、CI_Form_validationクラスを継承していじることとなりました。その手がかりとしてとても助かりました、ありがとうございます。